# ASP.NET Core 3.1 app straight out of the box runs in VS 2019 but not from iis. Getting HTTP Error 500.19 0x8007000d

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm publishing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application with no content (i.e. straight out of the box) and getting the title error when trying to run the website.

I'm using the Folder Profile option in 'Publish'.

What is unusual is the contents of the published folder - the folders are:

```
cs  de  es;
```

etc including

```
wwwroot;  zh-hans;  zh-hant;  appsettings.development.json 
appsettings.json 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.dll 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.dll 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.dll 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll 
System.Text.Json.dll 
web.config 
WebTest.deps.json 
WebTest.dll 
WebTest.exe 
WebTest.pdb 
WebTest.runtimeconfig.json 
WebTest.Views.dll 
WebTest.Views.pdb
```

The web.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebTest.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
!--ProjectGuid: FAD94D81-0B07-4B20-8215-9AD183B65D61--
```

I've tried an assortment of option changes with no effect.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, thanks

Further to your comments:
Running from IIS Manager the error is:
*
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error
*
Publshed again:
set target = win-x64 instead of Portable
Self-contained

*
I ran dotnet webtest.dll as suggested and got no obvious errors.
Ran again from IIS manager and got the same error!

```
C:\Temp\WebDemos\AnnaMayTestFolder>dotnet webtest.dll
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]
      Hosting starting
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[37]
      Reading data from file 'C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-5f27c4fc-fa29-4712-a66e-a5c00fd8c31c.xml'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[37]
      Reading data from file 'C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-a07760bd-83a7-4ff1-963d-370c2bbee546.xml'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[18]
      Found key {5f27c4fc-fa29-4712-a66e-a5c00fd8c31c}.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[18]
      Found key {a07760bd-83a7-4ff1-963d-370c2bbee546}.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver[13]
      Considering key {a07760bd-83a7-4ff1-963d-370c2bbee546} with expiration date 2020-09-05 18:58:12Z as default key.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator[0]
      Forwarded activator type request from Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 to Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor[51]
      Decrypting secret element using Windows DPAPI.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator[0]
      Forwarded activator type request from Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 to Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngCbcAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory[4]
      Opening CNG algorithm 'AES' from provider '(null)' with chaining mode CBC.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngCbcAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory[3]
      Opening CNG algorithm 'SHA256' from provider '(null)' with HMAC.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[2]
      Using key {a07760bd-83a7-4ff1-963d-370c2bbee546} as the default key.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionHostedService[0]
      Key ring with default key {a07760bd-83a7-4ff1-963d-370c2bbee546} was loaded during application startup.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[2]
      Failed to locate the development https certificate at '(null)'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[0]
      Using development certificate: CN=localhost (Thumbprint: 5D0B4342CC4EAD5ED23E1752F64EC374F9EE941C)
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      No listening endpoints were configured. Binding to http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001 by default.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[0]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly WebTest
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: C:\Temp\WebDemos\AnnaMayTestFolder
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
Hosting started

*
Could anyone confirm that the Publish Target output folder structure shown above is typical? It looks completely wrong to me! What would a typical published folder look like? This is my first attempt at building a web site.

I am now completely stumped having researched all that I can on this problem. If anyone can help further that would be good.

Comment: I've checked bitness in app and iis application pool; folder security access for user/system/etc. Now stumbling in the dark!

Comment: Run the app from console and check the error. Change the `LogLevel` inside the `appsettings.json`

Comment: Add the error, we can't know what's happening without it.

Comment: Have a look if you have installed .net core 3.1 sdk. It happened to me once that I didn't have proper sdk installed on the server.

Comment: Running from IIS Manage the error is:
*
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Error Code    0x8007000d
Config Error    
*
Publshed again:
set target = win-x64 instead of Portable
Self-contained

*
I ran dotnet webtest.dll as suggested (see Next comment) and got no obvious errors.
Ran again from IIS manager and got the same error!

Comment: Please see edits to original post.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html The report tells.

Comment: @Gusman The error is: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Error Code: 0x8007000d

Answer (score 0):

As was stated by Max, run `dotnet WebTest.dll` from its directory using a command prompt or powershell on the server. This should give you a more detailed explanation of the issue. If you are not publishing the application as Self-Contained then you will need to install the server hosting bundle (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle), if you've not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

Publish Target output folder structure shown above is typical.

When you deploy your app on IIS (local or remote) make sure your target folder has following security permission:

[image]

Comment: I tried giving Full Control to IIS IUSRS and IIS IUSRS (MyMachine\IIS_IUSRS) but it did not make any difference.

Comment: @PatMcGowan Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges some HTTP ports are not allowed by default in IIS

Comment: @Mohammand Barbast Just to be clear. I can run the website from inside visual studio with IIS Express and all is ok. However, after publishing the site to a local folder, i try to run the website from inside IIS Manager and get the above error. Do you think publishing to a server is worth a try? I'm ok with the cost of doing this and if it works thats ok.

Comment: @PatMcGowan Maybe that's because of your HTTP port. I've seen somewhere that by default we are allowed to use 44300-44399 port range as our app SSL port. Have a search on Google for more information.

Comment: @PatMcGowan I remember i came across with the same problem as yours and that was concerned with port configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Running from IIS Manager the error is: * HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server
> Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. Error Code 0x8007000d Config Error

If you're still facing this issue:
please confirm that IIS is loading AspNetCoreModuleV2 for this site in [modules on IIS manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#querying-adding-and-removing-modules-using-the-iis-manager)
You could also [enable failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis#enable-failed-request-tracing) in IIS, to confirm that the request reaches the ANCM or somehow fails before then.

Visual studio can start up these sites via a helper application that runs the .net core kestrel server app, but 'standalone' published sites need the [ASP.net core hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0) installed to get the 'AspNetCoreModule' (link provides download URL of the 'hosting bundle installer' and steps to check if the ANCM dll is present).

Like with other missing modules, IIS indicates 'configuration errors' if it can't parse sections of a web.config it doesn't recognize, perhaps that is the case here.